# Save django Models in different script and run that script with HTML button

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-4.0

I have model.py as

```py
    class Fruit(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
        weight = models.IntegerField(max_length=16)
        color = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    class Veg(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
        weight = models.IntegerField(max_length=16)
```

I have myFunction.py as

```
    
    def makeModels(file):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            line=f.readline()
            while line:
                 if line.split(',')[0] == 'fruit':
                      a = Fruit(name=line.split(',')[1], weight=line.split(',')[2],
                                 color=line.split(',')[3])
                      a.save()
                 if line.split(',')[0] == 'veg':
                      b = Veg(name = line.split(',')[1], weight = line.split(',')[2]
                      b.save()
                 line = f.readline()
```

and files as abc.txt

"fruit,apple,3,red\n
fruit,banana,1,green\n
veg,spinach,4\n
veg,collard,2\n
fruit,banana,3,yelow\n
veg,broccoli,3\n
fruit,orange,1,orange"

I want to create an HTML button to trigger this function/script and also create a celery scheduler to schedule a trigger to run at a time on a daily basis. This is on a django framework.

Please help me on how to approach it. The running external function to save models through html button and scheduling it part.  Thank you!

Comment: With regards to the HTML button, you would need to create a view that calls the `makeModels` function, then in `urls.py` have that view called when a url is accessed.  I don't use celery, but I'm sure the documentation for celery will help. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you @ja408 how do I create a cbv that calls makeModels.  I am a bit new to django.